# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - Swift with NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to make a simple web browser application in Swift to learn the language. Right now, I'm stuck on allowing the user to tap a bookmark they recently added, and having the webview load the certain url.

To decide which URL to choose, I have this in my BookmarkTVC (TableViewController with bookmarks)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    vc.gotoWebsite(bookmarks[indexPath.row].url)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

EDIT: Screenshot of BookmarksTVC: https://i.stack.imgur.com/00tMl.jpg

I know 100% that the

> bookmarks[indexPath.row].url

is getting the right string, because I println'd it.

Now, this is my `vc.gotoWebsite` function

```
func gotoWebsite(link: String) {
    // Format Link
    var formattedLink: String!

    if link.hasPrefix("http://") || link.hasPrefix("https://") {
        formattedLink = link
    } else if link.hasPrefix("www.") {
        formattedLink = "http://\(link)"
    } else {
        formattedLink = "http://www.\(link)"
    }

    // Goto formatted link
    println(formattedLink)
    let url = NSURL(string: formattedLink)
    println(url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    println(request)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

On the `webView.loadRequest(request)` line, I get:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

this is the breakpoint (Image): http://imgur.com/S7dMswD&4pdL4xX

even though I have println'd the `request` variable and got the response

`<NSURLRequest: 0x7fb9c8616700> { URL: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl, headers: (null) }`

Please help. Again, all I'm trying to do is get the url that is ssociated with the table view cell that the user clicked. Then, I'm using that string and calling a method from another class that goes to that URL.

Comment: Well, if you're sure the request isn't nil, then it's probably webView that's nil, given that it's the only other variable on that line...

Comment: this method works when I call it from other methods inside the ViewController class, just not when I call it from other classes... hmmmmmmmmmm. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I'm thinking that webView is presumably an IBOutlet-connected variable which would be set up when the view loads, which hasn't happened. Note that creating a view controller from a nib [doesn't necessarily load its view and instantiate things](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593395/iboutlets-not-being-set-except-when-creating-throwaway-variables-during-initwith).

Comment: @ Matt Gibson, you're a genius!! So, how would I go about initializing this IBOutlet Webview?

Comment: having the exact same issue. did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No @dandoen, I wasn't able to solve this. :( I know that was right, because it makes perfect sense, but I have no idea on how to wait till the webView is initialized before going to the website.

Comment: Yeah, same here. Called vc.loadView() before calling (in your case) the gotoWebsite method. This did solve the code breaking but the UIWebView was still empty. In my case I only had two view controllers, so I solved it using just by using two different VCs.

Comment: Did you try to unwrap your index like vc.gotoWebsite(bookmarks[indexPath!.row].url)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem. I overcame it by adding a `request` parameter to my `UIViewController` `vc` which displays the `UIWebView`:

```
var request: NSURLRequest? {
   didSet {
       if request != nil { // didSet is called even if you are setting request to nil :-(
           webView?.loadRequest(request!) // do not load request if webView is nil
       }
    }
}
```

and then in the same viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...
    if request != nil {
        webView.loadRequest(request!)
    }
}
```

so I can write in the calling code which instantiates the vc, instead of `webView.loadRequest()`,

```
vc.request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlAsString)!)
```

and that will either trigger the webView to load via the `didSet` function if the webView has been defined by then, or, if it hasn't, will cause the webView to load in the viewDidLoad later. I don't know if that is perfect, but it works for me.